# Unfasten unfamiliar springs that fix an old mirror to its frame

Tags: repair, mirror

I have obtained an old mirror that needs restoration. Its design suggests to me it may be from the 1950s and there is a French-language label on the back side, so maybe its provenance is French as well. (It is almost certainly European.) There are four metals springs at the back corners that fix the mirror (its wooden back side) into the metal frame.

I am wondering this: How can I remove (or unfasten those springs) in such a way that I can temporarily remove the mirror from its frame, clean the (rusty) springs, and put everything back together again? For instance, are such springs kept in their fixation holes also by spring forces and could I pull them out there without damaging the hole?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pull gently outward (axially, away from the spring loop) while pulling the bent spring tabs up and out of the holes. Spring tension will increase while you pull so it may help to have someone hold the frame. The wire is pretty rusty so do not overstretch or it could break.